# Redis administration panel

Tags: redis

Is there a standard or de facto standard GUI administration panel for Redis? I'd like to see general health and status of my Redis instances through a web interface. Advanced stuff such as access to logs, trends on memory usage, etc. would be nice but not necessary. I'm running Redis on a Hadoop cluster, in which I enjoy having pages for the JobTracker, NameNode, Ganglia, etc.

There are a few out there, but at first glance they don't seem ready for prime time.

- http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=381
- http://code.google.com/p/redis-admin/

Comment: Try redisdesktop (http://redisdesktop.com/)

Comment: Try FastoRedis (http://fastoredis.com)

Comment: Check out [phpRedisAdmin](https://github.com/ErikDubbelboer/phpRedisAdmin), its a simple web interface written in php. Demo link [is here](http://dubbelboer.com/phpRedisAdmin)

Comment: Try [Keylord](http://protonail.com/products/keylord) - this is GUI application for Windows, Linux and MAC OS X for manage key-value databases.

Answer (score 44):

I am a big fan of [Redis-Commander](https://github.com/joeferner/redis-commander)

Comment: Seems pretty decent until you get a reasonable number of keys. We only have 30k in our prod DB and bringing up redis-commander against that caused the webpage to chew up 5GB.

Comment: You may want to give a try to Redsmin in this case, it handles hundreds of thousand of keys in a breeze.

Answer (score 13):

Give a try to [Redsmin](https://redsmin.com) ([long description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12316197/745121)). Its a **fully online** GUI for Redis that provides a lot of features.

It currently offers:

- **No installation** and cross-platform
- Multiple **database management** (with direct or proxied access)
- Keys [tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGPw4.gif) and list view (with [optional real-time update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA7Ab.gif))
- Batch operation over multiple key that match a pattern
- **Data editor**
- **LUA** editor

[image: Redis LUA Editor]

- **Redis Cluster** monitoring
- Online **configuration** (with [command override support](https://i.imgur.com/Xbjonco.gif))
- JavaScript API directly accessible from the browser console for light data processing

[image: Redis JavaScript API]

- [**Monitoring** features](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JA9UvdgJ_GI)
- Online **terminal** with auto-completion and **inline-documentation**
- Real-time **data-visualization** (histogram, pie, ...)
- **Monitoring** (and alerting soon)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks quite slick and promising. I'll check it out. Thanks!!

Comment: any news when will it be available for sign up? (now it is only possible to submit for future invite)

Comment: We just sent the next wave of invites. We are really excited to hear what you think of it!

Comment: Cannot connect to any redis instance. What is the connection string and server address given my server runs as windows service at 127.0.0.1:6379?

Comment: It is not mentioned that NodeJS is required to run Redsmin when connecting to a local host thus it is not as hassle free as Service Stack AdminUI's Ajax client.

Comment: In fact we plan to port the redsmin-proxy to python as other well known SaaS like New Relic did. Redsmin is still easier to use than to install a full self-hosted solution that sometimes requires its own database.

Comment: They are nothing but cheaters. They do not send any invites, they do not answer any e-mails.

Comment: Hello Green, we answer every emails and we send invites every 3-4 weeks, send me your email in PM and I'll see what went wrong, thanks!

Comment: Redsmin is out of beta! http://blog.redsmin.com/post/64614784721/we-are-out-of-beta

Comment: It should also be added that Redsmin is not free, its pretty expensive too when you have a few servers to monitor - there are plenty of free alternatives, which given the nature of Redis, the installation of which shouldn't tax anyone too much if they know enough to know that they need one.

Comment: @SteveChilds Redsmin is also available for free for 1 connected Redis server with every premium options that alternatives can't or do not provide (like real-time monitoring and alerting).

Answer (score 12):

I've been running [Redmon](https://github.com/steelThread/redmon) for a few days and it does a nice job graphing the live redis memory usage and keyspace, activity in a web UI with a CLI for typing redis commands too.  It's a Ruby application which was very easy to run once the dependencies were installed.

Comment: Isn't updated? It still refers older Redis version.:(

Answer (score 8):

`redis-cli info` provides a wealth of information about the health of a redis instance. Formatting its output for easier digestion shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 6):

You can also try [phpredmin](https://github.com/sasanrose/phpredmin). It provides simple statistics about your redis and a panel for manipulating databases and keys

Comment: looks nice, what is your experience with it ?

Answer (score 3):

I just found another redis admin program, single file, very easy to set up (I had to change the redis autoloader require on line 60 of the program). It's simple, but sufficient!

[code.google.com/p/php-redis-browser](http://code.google.com/p/php-redis-browser/)

Comment: I like single files stuff :)

Answer (score 3):

There is also the project [RedWeb](https://github.com/tnm/redweb/).
It is written in Python, and is built on the Bottle micro-framework.

Comment: It looks like its in Ruby, not python