# Redis data explorer

Tags: python, redis

Is there any tool to explore the redis data?

I am using redis module with Python

I see a [blog](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1010844204/redis-memory-usage) with showing stats and thought if there is some people already using

Thank you

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394731/phpmyadmin-equivalent-to-mysql-for-redis

Comment: Or this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/13445660/745121

Answer (score 1):

You can use redis-cli it does the job, I am not sure what a data exploration tool for redis would looks like anyway, a big list with all the keys ?

Here is an example of how you can explore your data:

# list all the keys
  keys *

# list all the keys starting with zz
  keys zz*

# check the data type
  type mykey