# How Can I Browse/View The Values Stored in Redis

Tags: nosql, redis

Are there any good browsers/explorer for viewing Redis out there ?
Am new to Redis so my expectation is if there is something similar to MongoVUE,Toad or SQLExplorer.

I tried Redis Admin UI from service stack but ran into 500 error when trying on IIS

Comment: Redis Admin from ServiceStack is the best that is available out there - http://www.servicestack.net/RedisAdminUI/AjaxClient/. There really isn't a great UI for redis, most people tend to use the command line client.

Comment: @Sripathi Krishnan I tried setting it up on Win 7 using IIS (am no expert with IIS) and ran into 500 error.. I looked up and finally gave up..It was too time consuming

Comment: I suggest moving this question to [softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) where it likely is on-topic.
As this question is closed for 2 years now, some of the answers are outdated and newer ones are missing.

Comment: If you're using Azure Cache for Redis, fastest option is just open up the redis console built into the Azure Portal, and run commands like SCAN and GET, just like using redis-cli! (Tip, don't use KEYS) :-)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you prefer **open-source desktop tools**, also take a look on [Redis Desktop Manager](http://rdm.dev/).

It's a cross-platform open source Redis DB management tool (i.e. Admin GUI)

*Disclaimer*: I am the creator and maintainer of this application.

[image: redis desktop manager screen]

Comment: I'm recommending over the Redsmin solution as it is FOSS and seems more similar to MongoVUE as the original question requested.

Comment: Very neat and usable interface..

Comment: with last ubuntu - not working

Comment: I can't figure out how to get this working with a password-less redis setup.

Comment: Unfortunately, this don't work with Windows Azure Redis

Comment: Yes it works with Azure Redis Cache

Comment: @shongololo RDM 0.8.0+ uses SCAN command for redis-server 2.8+ and KEYS if you connecting to old redis-server. Furthermore in settings you can specify glob style pattern for SCAN/KEYS command to load in tree only subset of keys.

Comment: @uglide, thanks for clarifying, submitted issue to github.

Comment: didn't work at windows 10

Comment: It's no more free for `mac os` devices.

Comment: Something recently happened that broke this tool's interface pretty badly. Not sure what occurred but older versions worked fine and new version is almost not usable

Comment: Windows and OS X binaries now require a subscription.

Comment: Its not oepnsource anymore

Comment: @MarufAlom It's still opensource, you can build it yourself for free.
https://docs.rdm.dev/en/latest/install/#build-from-source

Comment: [RedisInsight](https://redis.com/redis-enterprise/redis-insight/) is the ["official" redis-backed GUI](https://redis.com/blog/so-youre-looking-for-the-redis-gui/) as of 2019.

Answer (score 91):

[Redis Commander](http://joeferner.github.io/redis-commander/) is great if you're using node.js already.

Super simple to get going with NPM:

```
npm install -g redis-commander
redis-commander
```

Then point your browser at the address in the console

Comment: It doesn't seem to work if you have a lot of keys though... It keeps crashing for me with a 20000+ keys database.

Comment: On second command brings redis-commander :command not found

Comment: The docker image is broken as well, has been for at least half a year

Comment: Followed the steps, installed but crashed.

Comment: Redis Commander worked really well for my very simple needs. Needed something very simple to use and also free ($). Does not have many frills but allows you to connect to a redis database, view and manage keys/value pairs and that is about it. Also has a redis cli built in which could be convenient as well.

Comment: On Ubuntu Focal 20.04 LTS it fails to run with: `Error: yargs supports a minimum Node.js version of 12.`

Comment: This worked great for me out of the box, when none of the other solutions below did. Just needed to quickly debug redis storage was working as expected.

Answer (score 31):

Maybe you could give a try to **[Redsmin](http://redsmin.com)**.

It offers:

- Cross-platform, works everywhere inside a browser.
- Real-time and historical **Monitoring** and **Alerting** features
- Multiple **database management** with direct (plain text connection), direct (TLS/SSL connection) or proxied access for local instances behind a firewall.
- Batch operation over multiple key that match a pattern (delete, rename, duplicate)
- **Value editor**
- Online **configuration**
- JavaScript API directly accessible from the browser console for light data processing

[image: Redis JavaScript API]

- **Lua Editor**

[image: Redis LUA Editor]

- Online **terminal** with auto-completion and **inline-documentation**
- Real-time **data-visualization**

[image]
[image]

Full disclosure: I founded Redsmin.

[image]

Comment: @FGRibreau, I tried to get redsmin running but failed on my windows machine. Is there a link on your website or anywhere else, for that matter, that describes to get it up and running?

Comment: Any reason why you have an invalid SSL Cert? I'm reluctant to check this out because if it.

Comment: Oh that is just because we still did not find a good Wildcard SSL Cert provider, if you know one be my guest!

Comment: Hey @FGRibreau, I've tried installing redsmin on my OS X Mavericks box.  Everything installs correctly and when I run redsmin start I get the expected info:    `Redsmin daemon started. PID: 68756.`  Immediately afterward when I use `redsmin status` I get `error:   Redsmin daemon is not running.`.  `etc/log.log` is 0 bytes.  What's up?

Comment: Hello Thomson, it may be related to your node version or it may be a permission issue. I sent you an email with some point to check. For anybody else reading this, if you need support contact me directly at fg[at]redsmin.com !

Comment: Requires subscription for OS X, the one that ultimately worked the best for me on OS X was Redis-Commander (mentioned in another answer)

Comment: You should put TL;DR; answer about Real-time data-visualization, which looks like an answer to the OP question, in the first place, before all the other advertising. Also, I don't have the "Editor" tab.

Answer (score 14):

I just published [rebrow](https://github.com/marians/rebrow/), a web-based Redis browser written in Python. The feature set is limited, but it's free and open, so you might be able to add what you need.

There is a Docker image to get you started quickly.

Comment: This is actually very useful as you can spin it up as a Docker instance and therefore use it in Kubernetes, Openshift, etc...

Comment: NB! No password support :/

Comment: It would be great if it supported passwords...shame that PRs that add support have not been merged.

Answer (score 8):

I really like [qredis](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/qredis/0.1.7), it is a Python + Qt graphical interface to explore redis databases that should deserve more popularity IMO.

Comment: qredis home is https://github.com/tiagocoutinho/qredis

Comment: Fails to install on ubuntu 20.04: `No module named setuptools`.

Answer (score 5):

Definitively have a look at [Redis React](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/RedisReact).

Comment: Redis React is deprecated for Redis Vue apparently.

Answer (score 4):

If you're into ruby, there is [`redis-browser`](http://github.com/monterail/redis-browser) gem.

It's basically a Sinatra application so it can be mounted into any rack-based app, e.g. Ruby on Rails or it can run as standalone.

*Disclaimer: I am one of the maintainers of this gem.*