# Manage AWS redis from Windows

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

I've setup an AWS Elsticache (redis) which i want to be able to administer. Flush, delete entries etc from a Windows machine.

I've been googling this an havent been able to find any solutions.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by creating a VM in aws Domain and installing Redis Desktop Manager in that Domain.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give a try to a fully-featured GUI like [**Redsmin**](http://redsmin.com/) for that. See this question [**for a list of alternatives**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292351/is-there-a-good-redis-browser).