# Querying Redis metadata tables

Tags: redis

I am making graphical client for multiple databases and would like to add support for Redis.
I am new to Redis, and therefore have a very newbie question: Is there a way to browse Redis **metadata** (like sysobjects in MSSQL).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a good Redis browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292351/is-there-a-good-redis-browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is a key-value store, so instead of a metadata schema use some commands like `SCAN`, `KEYS`, `HSCAN`... to fetch all the keys in the database, each of this commands are for the different data types (STRING, HASH, LIST, SET), then depending on the type is possible to create a graphical representation of the data.