# GUI for managing Redis

Tags: user-interface, redis

Is there a standalone desktop GUI for managing Redis instances?

Up till now the only things I have found and tried are web-based solutions running either on your or on someones else host. They are also required to install node.js/ruby/python. The list of things I previously checked:

- [Redis commander](https://github.com/joeferner/redis-commander)
- [Redmond](http://steelthread.github.io/redmon/)
- [Redsmin](https://redsmin.com)

What I am looking at is something like [MongoVUE](http://www.mongovue.com/) for Mongo or [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/products/navicat-for-mysql) for MySQL (desktop GUI with no additional installation required running on your local machine).

Please note that the [popular SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7716446/1090562) addresses a slightly different question - any GUI and the answers are just about web-gui interfaces.

Comment: Hello, Redsmin founder here, just to let you know that Redsmin will soon offer a standalone virtual appliance (like Github enterprise).

Comment: Try FastoRedis http://fastoredis.com, Shell-centric cross-platform Redis management tool. Work on most linux systems, have deb and rpm packages.

Comment: How come this is off topic but [a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292351/is-there-a-good-redis-browser) isn't?

Comment: @ArturGaspar magic of SO :-)

Comment: can someone update this for 2021 and add free ones and paid ones ?